# Template argument deduction and default template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

The code below compiles and works as I want it to with clang and gcc but gives an error with Visual Studio 2015 RTM. I think clang and gcc are correct to allow this but I'm not sure. Should this code compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, size_t N, typename IS = decltype(std::make_index_sequence<N>{})>
struct Vector {
    T e_[N];
};

template <typename T, typename U, size_t N, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto operator+(const Vector<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>& x,
                         const Vector<U, N>& y) {
    using V = std::common_type_t<T, U>;
    return Vector<V, N>{x.e_[Is] + y.e_[Is]...};
}

int main() {
    const auto v0 = Vector<float, 4>{1, 2, 3, 4};
    const auto v1 = Vector<float, 4>{5, 6, 7, 8};
    const auto v2 = v0 + v1;
    for (auto x : v2.e_) std::cout << x << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Visual Studio compiles this ok if I change operator+ to:

```
template <typename T, typename U, size_t N, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto operator+(const Vector<T, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>& x,
                         const Vector<U, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>& y);
```

But I don't think it should be necessary to put the `std::index_sequence<Is...>` again for `y`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `decltype(std::make_index_sequence<N>{})` is entirely nonsensical and should just be `std::make_index_sequence<N>`.

Comment: @orlp Good point. Not sure how I missed that - I'm in the process of refactoring the real code this was extracted from which is how that ended up there. Changing it makes the problem go away in VS2015 interestingly.

Comment: Then that is a compiler bug, because while nonsensical, they should be equivalent.

Comment: @orlp agreed, you've solved my problem though so thanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

`IS` should not be part of the type of `Vector` at all. Instead, use a helper function:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Vector {
    T e_[N];
};

template <typename T, typename U, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
inline constexpr auto add_impl(const Vector<T, N>& x, const Vector<U, N>& y,
                               std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using V = std::common_type_t<T, U>;
    return Vector<V, N>{x.e_[Is] + y.e_[Is]...};
}

template <typename T, typename U, std::size_t N,
          typename Is = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
constexpr auto operator+(const Vector<T, N>& x, const Vector<U, N>& y) {
    return add_impl(x, y, Is());
}
```

I don't have access to VS2015 to test this, but it should work.

Comment: That's how I was originally doing things. There's a few advantages to refactoring it this way though. Not least of which is it lets me work around another Visual Studio 2015 bug with `constexpr` :-) The main motivation though is reducing inlining depth in debug builds.